# CSS: Table - Row with colspan - change whole row color on hover

Tags: html, css

I hope this is not duplicated. I wish the whole row had color changed on `tr[child]:hover`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style type="text/css">

  tr[origin]:hover {
   background-color: grey;
  }

  tr[origin]:hover + tr[child]{
   background-color: grey;
  }

  tr[child]:hover {
   background-color: grey;
  }

 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <table border="1px">

  <tr origin>
   <td rowspan="2">1</td>
   <td colspan="2">Question</td>
   <td rowspan="2">2/3</td>
   <td rowspan="2">View answer</td>
  </tr>
  <tr child>
   <td>Rasp 1</td>
   <td>Rasp2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr origin>
   <td rowspan="2">1</td>
   <td colspan="2">Question</td>
   <td rowspan="2">2/3</td>
   <td rowspan="2">View answer</td>
  </tr>
  <tr child>
   <td>Rasp 1</td>
   <td>Rasp2</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **css cannot help you here**. CSS do not have selector going up the tree, it can only select the next sibbling. You can do `[child]:hover + tr {background:..}` but   `[child]:hover - tr {background:..}` do not exist :)

Comment: Sad. Why didn't w3c adopt the 'previous sibling selector' yet?

Comment: For the same trouble with the parent selector . cascade .. , and it would require much ressource to go throught the html tree in both ways from every tag of the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a very interesting question !

You can use `tbody` for that.
You are allowed to put more than one `tbody` in a table according to w3 [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3).

> Table rows may be grouped into a table head, table foot, and one or more table body sections [...]

```css
tbody:hover {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<table border="1px">

  <tbody>
    <tr origin>
      <td rowspan="2">1</td>
      <td colspan="2">Question</td>
      <td rowspan="2">2/3</td>
      <td rowspan="2">View answer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr child>
      <td>Rasp 1</td>
      <td>Rasp2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr origin>
      <td rowspan="2">1</td>
      <td colspan="2">Question</td>
      <td rowspan="2">2/3</td>
      <td rowspan="2">View answer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr child>
      <td>Rasp 1</td>
      <td>Rasp2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap each row's td elements in tbody and target it in css:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">

        tbody[row]:hover {
            background-color: grey;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1px">
      <tbody row>
        <tr origin>
            <td rowspan="2">1</td>
            <td colspan="2">Question</td>
            <td rowspan="2">2/3</td>
            <td rowspan="2">View answer</td>
        </tr>
        <tr child>
            <td>Rasp 1</td>
            <td>Rasp2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody row>
        <tr origin>
            <td rowspan="2">1</td>
            <td colspan="2">Question</td>
            <td rowspan="2">2/3</td>
            <td rowspan="2">View answer</td>
        </tr>
        <tr child>
            <td>Rasp 1</td>
            <td>Rasp2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```